# In the onload event, attach an event handler to the submit button so when it is clicked it calls the function displayFullName

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea how to  combine the first name and last name into one field.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id); 
        }
        function displayFullName() {

            // display those fields as the full name in the fullName input field
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            //  attach an event handler in the onload event that calls the function displayFullName
            //  when the  button (id = goButton) is clicked.
            displayFullName();
            
        }
        
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <label>FIRST NAME</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
        
        <label>LAST NAME</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
        
        <input type="button" id="goButton" value="Submit" onclick=window.onload>
        
        <input type="text" id="fullName" disabled>
        
        </body>
        
        
        
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding a document.getElementById("fullname").value = true; but it didnt work.

Comment: You're not adding an event listener to the submit button anywhere. You're calling `displayFullName()` when the page is first loaded, before the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything.

Comment: You can combine the names with `fname + " " + lname`

Comment: The instructions say "attach an event listener to the submit button".

Comment: Why did you define `$` if you're not using it?

Comment: This seems like homework and it doesn't look like you've made any attempt to do what it actually asks you to do. It would be cheating if I wrote an answer showing how to do it.